# What's the matter with Planck mass $M_P$ in Einstein-Hilbert action?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, units, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

The [Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) is often written as $$S_{EH}=\frac{c^4}{16\pi G}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R\tag{1}$$ and often as

$$S_{EH}=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}M_P^2 R\tag{2}.$$ Comparing (1) and (2), one has $M_P=\frac{c^2}{4\sqrt{\pi G}}$. But the definition of [Planck mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_mass) is given by $M_P=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}$.

$\bullet$ *How do we reconcile these two different expressions for $M_P$? Do I misunderstand something?*

$\bullet$ *Both (1) and (2) are classical action, and therefore, the action should not contain $\hbar$. In that case, how is form (2) of the action justified?*

Comment: Have you checked the dimensional consistency of each equation?

Answer (score 8):

You are comparing apples with oranges.

Let's first agree on the dimensions of the relevant quantities, basically Freshman physics:

$$[G] = L^3 M^{-1} T^{-2} \\
[S]=
M L^2 T^{-1}\\
[\kappa]=\left [\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}\right ]= T^2 M^{-1} L^{-1} \\
[m_p]=\left [\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{8\pi G}}\right ]  = M \\
[R]=L^{-2} \\
[d^4x]= L^3 T.
$$
The last line is what Feynman uses in his lectures that passed on to the WP article you are quoting. Landau and Lifschitz, *Classical theory of fields*, §93, do not use his $dx^0=dt$, but $=c~ dt$ instead, so their
$[d^4x]=L^4$ which most people carry in their gut, because it is really so much more sensible, but it may lead to misconceptions.

So your formula (1) jibes just fine,
$$
M L^2 T^{-1}= L M T^{-2} ~~ L^{-2} ~~ L^3 T.
$$

With the exception of QFTheorists and quantum gravity types, nobody needs use the *reduced* Planck mass defined above. Nevertheless, since power counting is second nature to them, and they are practical people, they bypass the mess by simply rewriting, instead of your (2), for a start (only!),
$$
 S_{EH}=\frac{ 1}{ 2\kappa}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R = \frac{c^3 m_p^2}{2\hbar}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R . 
$$
You appreciate $\hbar$ is not really there, as it was only inserted to neutralize/eliminate itself in the Planck mass.

However, you never see this, since QFTheorists use [HEP natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#"Natural_units"_(particle_physics_and_cosmology)), $c=\hbar=1$: their world is steeped in relativity and QM, so they rely on them as conversion units. In this world, then, everything becomes simple and  wholesome, in no time,
$$
S_{EH}=  \frac{ m_p^2}{2 }\int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R ~. 
$$
So wholesome, in fact, that one can grow oblivious of the underlying structure--and the Feynman-L&L notation disparity, now invisible.

The Planck mass is about the weight of a hundredth of a grain of sugar, so, then, minuscule when it comes to classical gravitational effects, but *huge*, O(10<sup>18</sup> GeV), when considering energies of ordinary particles-- a particle that heavy would have its Compton wavelength recede inside its own Schwarzschild radius; the perfect background unit, then.